# how to display a list of pictures in horizontal layout

Tags: image, algorithm, jsf-2

[image: <code>need algo to design this screen</code>]

I need help to make algo that help me to display images like this. The list size of pic is not fixed. There may be 10 pic or 100 pic. I'm making this site in JSF.

Comment: You can use `h:panelGrid columns="3"` and `h:panelGrid columns="1"` for content of second column. For repeat it `ui:repeat` can be used.

Comment: hello Vasil i'm using  ui:repeat the problem is that i don't know how many pic are in db and what are there sequence. that is predefine layout to display pic like this way in client side .... I'm searching a good approach . the problem is that if the one pic is missing from list the a blank spot remain in that place which is very bad impression.

Comment: You can use the `h:panelGrid`'s `rendered` attribute not to display a whole row of pics. You could also wrap each `img` tag in a `ui:fragment` tag and conditionally render it just for the case it's not empty. You've got a wide range of choices.